# css property not appyling for div

Tags: css

In the below code, in the div section success and fail classes, the font color is not changing and the div statement getting the underline. The text-align and font-size applying the css correctly for success and fail, Please check

```
  <html>
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">            </script>  
  <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>  
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <style>

 td
 {
   height:40px;
 }
     select
     {
       spacing-left:50px;
     }
     .well-width
     {   
       height:400px;     
       border-radius:10px;     
       width:600px;        
      -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 20px grey;  
     }
     #title
     {
   font-weight:bold;
   font-size:38px;
   color:#f22144;
   font-family: 'Slabo 24px', serif;
     }
    #subtitle
    {
      color:green;
      font-size:25px;
      margin-left:80px;
      font-weight:bold;   
    }
    .success
    {
      text-align:center;
      font-size:25px;
      text-colour:green;
    }
    .fail
    {
      text-align:center;
      font-size:25px;
      colour: white;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-decoration-color: red;         
    }
       </style> 
     </head>
   <body>

     <div class="container">

       <br>
        <div class="well-width">    
         <br><Center><h1 style="color:green;font-family:'Arial Black';">       <u>GET RECEIPT<u></h1></center></br>
      <form method="post" action="#" autocomplete="off">   
        <center><table border=0>
         <tr>
             <td><label> Enter the Reference Number:</label></td>
             <td> <input type="text" name="ref" maxlength="10" required>  </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
             <td><label> Enter Roll Number:</label></td>
             <td> <input type="text" name="roll" maxlength="10" required></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan=2><center><input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Delete"></center></td>
        <tr>

         </table></center>
      </form>   
     </div>     
   </div>  
  <?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  include('connect.php');
  $ref=$_POST['ref'];
  $roll=$_POST['roll'];

  $sql="select * from registrations where id='$ref' and rollno='$roll'";
  $query=mysql_query($sql);
  $count=mysql_num_rows($query);
  if($count>0)
  {
   $sql1="delete from registrations where id='$ref' and rollno='$roll'" ;
   $query1=mysql_query($sql1);
    if($query1)
    {
      echo"<div class='success'>$count records deleted successfully</div>";
    }       
  }
  else
  {
    echo"<div class='fail'>No records found with this Refrence Id and Rollno</div>";

  }
}
  ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off your code quality is very bad. See. Please use a tool fix your issues.

[image]

Comment: Thats true friend. All the problems are solved. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It is not `text-colour:green;` it is `color: green;` same thing for `colour: white;`, it is `color: white;`.

Comment: I recommend you to use this **normalize.css** _https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/_ file when creating a project. It will help you to eliminate many weird things. Try to put in your **.fail** and **.success** class **text-decoration: none !important;**

Comment: To remove underline set this property to fail & success class.

display: inline-block;   It's due to some reason this thing is rendering.I think some issue in your code.

Comment: display: inline-block; in the class removing the underline but the text is not centered

Comment: This thing is due to your code.That's why we need to use this type of code.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are using wrong property name.

instead of this

```
text-decoration-color: red;
```

should be

```
color:red;
```

For **Success** class

Instead of this

```
text-colour: green;
```

Should be

```
color: green;
```

To change the color of font, you use the property color. To change the background color, you use background-color. Refer [this tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_text.asp)

**To remove underline set this property to fail & success class.**

**display: inline-block;**

It's due to some reason this thing is rendering.I think some issue in your code.

Answer (score 0):

you have spelling mistake in `color`, its `color` not `colour` so that's why its not work

and also not used `text-color` you use `color` so that it works

try this

```
color:green;  
color:white;
```

in your `css` code